# Agregar varios registros en un data table C#

Tags: c#, datatable

Muy buenas tengo una duda necesito agregar varios registros a un data table lo estoy tratando de agrgar con un foreach pero tengo un error que me dice "Esta fila ya pertenece a esta tabla." Este es mi codigo:

```
var clientePro = obj.Recuperar();
            DataTable tab = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr = tab.NewRow();
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Producto", typeof(String));
            tab.Columns.Add(dc);            
            dc = new DataColumn("Producto Falta", typeof(String));
            tab.Columns.Add(dc);                                   
            if (ViewState["data"] != null)
            {
                tab = (ViewState["data"] as DataTable);
            }
            else
            {                                               
                foreach (var name in clientePro.productosCliente)
                {
                    dr["Producto"] = name.producto;                                                            
                    tab.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                foreach (var name in clientePro.ProductosClienteIVC)
                {
                    dr["Producto Falta"] = name.producto;                                                            
                    tab.Rows.Add(dr);
                }                
                ViewState["data"] = tab;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que al momento de agregar, no creas un nuevo objeto DataRow por cada fila que deseas agregar a tu DataTable, es decir, estás intentando agregar varias veces al objeto DataTable un mismo DataRow:

```
var clientePro = obj.Recuperar(); 
DataTable tab = new DataTable(); 
//DataRow dr = tab.NewRow(); 
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Producto", typeof(String)); 
tab.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("Producto Falta", typeof(String)); 
tab.Columns.Add(dc);

if (ViewState["data"] != null) 
{ 
    tab = (ViewState["data"] as DataTable); 
} 
else {

    foreach (var name in clientePro.productosCliente) 
    {
        // Hay que crear un nuevo objeto por cada producto
        Datarow dr = tab.NewRow();
        dr["Producto"] = name.producto;
        tab.Rows.Add(dr);

     } 


     // En esta parte habría que ver si la propiedad 'ProductosClienteIVC' tiene la misma cantidad de elementos que 'productosCliente', de otro modo de marcará error
     int i = 0;
     foreach (var name in clientePro.ProductosClienteIVC) 
     { 
         tab.Rows[i]["Producto Falta"] = name.producto;
         i++;
     }

 ViewState["data"] = tab;
```

}